# How do you handle large relationship data attributes and compound documents?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

If an article has several comments (think thousands over time). Should `data.relationships.comments` return with a limit?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "articles",
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Some title",
      },
      "relationships": {
        "comments": {
          "links": {
            "related": "https://www.foo.com/api/v1/articles/1/comments"
          },
          "data": [
            { "type": "comment", "id": "1" }
            ...
            { "type": "comment", "id": "2000" }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "comments",
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "body": "Lorem ipusm",
      }
    },
    .....
    {
      "type": "comments",
      "id": 2000,
      "attributes": {
        "body": "Lorem ipusm",
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

This starts to feel concerning, when you think of compound documents (http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents). Which means, the `included` section will list all comments as well, making the JSON payload quite large.

Comment: Use an async relationship.

Comment: @Gaurav We do. But my main concern is the size of the payload, since the article resource is including all comments. Or is this not an issue?

Comment: do you have to include all the comments with the articles, or would it be ok to load them separately with pagination?

Comment: If you use an async relationship between article and comment, comments need not be in the included section in the article payload, and Ember Data will issue separate request(s) for them.

Comment: @andorov How would you suggest applying pagination on `data.relationships.comments` and for `comments` in `included`? It seems more rational to paginate articles. But haven't heard of paginating items in `data.relationships`. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Gaurav The `included` is mainly used for our iOS app. So the iOS app has a sense of "pre-loading" the data without any additional queries. But even still. Assuming I leave out `included`. `data.relationships.comments.data` would be a very big array. Which basically brings us back to the initial issue, where the payload would still be quite large

Comment: I suggest - do not load `comments` with `articles`.  When you need the `comments` for a particular article use `store.query` and pass the article id and `page=1` - return first page of `comments` with meta data about the pagination, and then query additional comment 'pages' if needed.  I can write out an official longer answer if so.

Comment: @andorov That was my initial thought. However, this would mean the iOS app would have to perform an additional query. The whole point of using a compound document, was to side load the data, so the iOS app already has it on the first query

Comment: you could sideload just the first page of comments

Comment: @andorov Hmmm, that's an interesting solution. Which means, if the iOS app needs more comments, then it would execute the comments endpoint with something like `filter[article-id]` params. At least, the iOS would have benefited from preloading the first page of the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of records you get at a time from a long list use pagination ([JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-pagination)).

I would load the `comments` separately with `store.query` ([ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_query)), like so -

```
store.query('comments', { author_id: <author_id>, page: 3 });
```

which will return the relevant subset of comments.

If you don't initially want to make two requests per author, you could include the first 'page' in the authors request as you're doing now.

You may also want to look into an addon like [Ember Infinity](https://github.com/hhff/ember-infinity) (untested), which will provide an infinite scrolling list and automatically make pagination requests.